# Determine the infinitesimal order of the function in $x0= 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: infinitesimal order. If you can explain me how you solve this
function:

$$(1+3x)^x -1 -x\ln(1+3x)$$

Mine resolution: $$(1+3x)^x$$ = 1 (taylor series)
                 $$xln(2+3x)$$ = $3x^2$
so $$lim \frac {1-1-3x^2}{x^n}$$= -3  (this is not equal to 0 so the infinitesimal order is 2? Is this the correct solution?)

Comment: The first such approximation is $f(0)$ but that's zero, which is why we don't like it. The next one is $f(0)+f'(0)x$. What does that look like?

Comment: This looks like Taylor polynom, right?

Comment: I have problems to determine this order. I tried to calculate derivates in 0

Comment: The order is the smallest $n$ such that $lim_{x\to0}f(x)/x^n$ doesn't tend to zero. First observe that order of a composition is the product of the orders, if both of them are positive. Then look at $e^{y}-1-y$, which is easy, and $x\ln(1+3x)$ which should also be easy.

Comment: Could you sum up into basic steps?

Comment: It is often a good idea when you are not making progress to backtrack and ask about the definition, i.e. what does "infinitesimal order" mean?  At the end you've made your way to trying to compute a limit, but it isn't clear how you think that relates to the Question.  The title is especially unclear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$x\ln(1+3x)=x\left(3x-\frac{9}{2}x^2+9x^3+o(x^3)\right)=3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+o(x^4)$$

$$(1+3x)^x=e^{x\ln(1+3x)}=e^{3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+o(x^3)}=1+3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+\frac{(3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+o(x^4))^2}{2}+o(x^4)=1+3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+\frac{9}{2}x^4+o(x^4)$$

thus

$$(1+3x)^x -1 -x\ln(1+3x)=1+3x^2-\frac{9}{2}x^3+9x^4+\frac{9}{2}x^4-1-3x^2+\frac{9}{2}x^3-9x^4+o(x^4)=\frac{9}{2}x^4+o(x^4)$$

Comment: The solution is 4, not 2 so. Thanks

Comment: Yes it seems to be 4, check the details of the calculation, fo you have any doubt?

Comment: Any doubt! Thanks so much!!